# How to fetch the list of Tags in TFS 2015 Update 3

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Is there a way to fetch the list of tags created for a team project, basically we need information such as creation date, created by user etc.

Can we fetch these information using TFS RestApi? If so it would be helpful if code snippets are provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't the information of created by user, you can check it in dbo.tbl_TagDefinition table of collection database.

To fetch the list of Tags, you can refer to Giulio’s answer, for example:

```
[collection URL]/_apis/tagging/scopes/[Team Project ID]/tags?api-version=1.0
```

To get Team Project ID, you can call this REST API:

```
[Collection URL]/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0
```

Simple code for C#:

```
String MyURI = "[collection URL]/_apis/tagging/scopes/f593de42-d419-4e07-afc7-1f334077c212/tags?api-version=1.0";
            WebRequest WReq = WebRequest.Create(MyURI);
            WReq.Credentials =
                new NetworkCredential("[user name]", "[password]", "[domain"");

            WebResponse response = WReq.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the content.
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, what fields in dbo.tbl_TagDefinition provides the created by user and creation date.

Comment: @Santhosh There isn't Created By User and Creation Date in dbo_TagDefinition, sorry for the mistake, I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a REST API to manage [Tags](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/tags), but there is not auditing information as per your request.

If you want to learn how to call a REST API there is plenty of sources, starting from the [Get started](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics) page.